# How to create a mask on multiple objects/effects in Davinci Resolve Fusion?

Tags: davinci-resolve, fusion

I'm a newbie and watched some tutorials but I couldn't do what I want to achieve. I'm not even sure if it's actually possible.

Consider I have a video clip. Then I want to blur it. Then I want to add a text title on it say "HELLO". I can easily do it using Fusion nodes. And here's how I do it:

[image]

Now, what I want is this:

[image]

OR even this (manual mask for specific shape):

[image]

Basically, it's the video clip, the blur effect and the text (certain portion of text) to be cropped according to any type of mask. A circle mask in this case.

One way would be create individual masks for the clip, for blur effect and lastly one for text and then put them together. I don't want to do that.

I just think that maybe it's possible to do with a single mask in the end. Something like we do in Premiere Pro where you could Nest everything and then crop/mask it.